# system() doesn't work for modifying the command line prompt

Tags: c++, ubuntu, console

I'm using C++ in Ubuntu and want to modify the command prompt. If I enter PS1=abc in the command line, the prompt becomes abc.

However, if I execute a program that calls to system("PS1=ABC"), the prompt doesn't change.

On the other hand, system() appears to work fine with different commands and the command line obeys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PS1` is an environment variable.  Every process has its own set of environment variables.

When you start a new process, it inherits a *copy* of its parent's environment.  Any changes to a process's environment will not affect the environment of its parent process.

The `system` function starts a new child process.  That means that `system("PS1=ABC")` launches a child process that sets its own `PS1` variable and then exits.

To modify an environment variable in your own process, use [`putenv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/putenv.3.html) (Linux and other Unix-likes) or [`SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setenvironmentvariable) (Windows).  Note that this still won't affect your parent process (likely the shell from which your program was launched), so setting `PS1` still won't have any affect unless you then subsequently launch another shell as a child.

Answer (score 1):

`system(command)` starts a sub process. Whenever it finishes, its whole environment is gone.

If you want to pass environment variables to the subprocess, look up `fork()` and `exec()`.

Or, if your're using Windows, `CreateProcess`.

Comment: Thanks, Ted. However, I have used system() to resize the command line window and it didn't returned to its original size when the subprocess finished.

Comment: That is probably true. `system` is usallly one of the last resourses one would use.

What you try to do is normally not possible. Don't worry about that. If you get subprocesses synchronized and feel confortable with that, you're fine.